# How to pull code from BitBucket with C# programmatically

Tags: c#, git, winforms, bitbucket

I am writing C# web forms application that needs to pull code for concerned tag on bitbucket.

I have discovered [SharpBucket](https://github.com/MitjaBezensek/SharpBucket) as potential solution. But I am not sure how to pull actual code.

It seems that SharpBucket API offers only meta data about repositories. All the the properties in Intelli Sense on the picture are of type string.

[image]

If SharpBucket can not pull the code, please advise on other options.

Comment: Please correct the spelling of "BitBucket" in question.

Answer (score 1):

I use [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) to programmatically access git repositories. Note that you may need to use it in conjunction with SharpBucket if you still want BitBucket-specific functionality.